# To do web app with calendar view and Google Calendar import

Tags: google-calendar, webapp-rec, calendar, tasks

Is there a Todo webapp which presents tasks in a calendar view which imports my events from Google Calendar so that task scheduling (at best with a hourly granularity) becomes less tedious?

With the apps I know I find myself constantly switching between my Google Calendar and the task list to schedule the tasks.

However, I don't need something simple like Google Tasks, but a full-fledged task management solution.

Have searched for something like this for years now, but never found it. The closest was [Producteev](http://www.producteev.com/) which allows to rearrange it's tasks in a calendar view, but only down to a daily granularity and it doesn't allow importing events from a Google Calendar (just exporting tasks to a Google Calendar which they have disabled a few months ago due to problems with the implementation).

Extra points for web apps with Android clients. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found something at least similar to what I've looked for: [zendone](http://www.zendone.com)

Zendone merges Evernote (used as GTD inbox) and Google calendar (used as GTD calendar) with a task management app - sync with both tools is bidirectional and instantaneous!

Google calendar events are not imported into the webapp, but the developers [acknowledge the need for such a feature](https://getsatisfaction.com/zendone/topics/more_calendars_monodirectional).

After having tested it for a few days I can absolutely recommend it to every GTD user out there.

IPhone and [Android](https://getsatisfaction.com/zendone/topics/android_app-ihnq3) apps are currently under development with the iPhone app having [nearly reached beta state](https://getsatisfaction.com/zendone/topics/how_to_sign_up_for_the_iphone_beta).

Answer (score 0):

Have tried [Doodle](http://doodle.com)? Great time scheduling but no todo feature so far.

Comment: Well, without task management this is sadly nothing for me...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will fit your needs but I use [Remember the Milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/) for scheduling my tasks.

It has some synchronization with Google Calendar, Gmail gadget and an AWESOME Android app.

The main drawback is it doesn't fully synchronize with Google Calendar—it only adds tasks to the day, but you can view all of them and even add new ones from within Google Calendar, so you won't have to switch apps.

Comment: RTM is great, but as truly daily scheduling isn't possible (like you already mentioned) it is not the thing I'm looking for. In addition to this I've always found their webapp... well, lacking especially in comparison to their perfectly designed Android app.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best comparisons I've found is actually [this table](http://www.toodledo.com/info/compare.php) from [toodledo](http://www.toodledo.com), even though they are comparing their competition I think they do a fairly honest job.

I am going to go out on a limb a little bit and say you might want to look at some project management tools as well. They might fit your needs, but can also get very complex if you're just looking for something simple.

Comment: Great find - the table is really interesting. Regarding pm tools - I already checked some of them out and found them overly complex for my everyday needs.